# Handling form submission with Javascript - How to give user another chance?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, event-handling, ruby-on-rails-5

My current application prevents blank and empty input from being submitted on the first attempt. If the initial input is valid, the search is executed. If it is invalid, the form becomes "unresponsive" and no other attempts can be made. How can I modify my code, ideally using plain JavaScript, to allow multiple attempts without reloading the page?

```
// welcome.js
function prepareEventHandlers() {
     document.getElementById("new_search").onsubmit = validateForm
}

function validateForm() {
    var q = document.getElementById("search_q").value;
    var trimmed_q = q.trim();
    if (trimmed_q.length < 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    prepareEventHandlers();
}


// segment from home.html.erb
<%= form_for :search, url: {action: "results"}, html: {id: "new_search", method: "get"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :q, placeholder: "Where to?", html: {id: "search_q"} %>
        <%= f.submit "Search" %>
    <% end %>

// rails generated html for home.html.erb -- omitted 30 lines of scripts from head
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="welcome.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  </script>
  </head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homeheader">
</div>
<div class="searchbar">
  <h3 class="col-md-2"></h3>
  <h3 class="col-md-10">
    <form id="new_search" action="/results" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        <input placeholder="Where to?" html="{:id=&gt;&quot;search_q&quot;}" type="text" name="search[q]" id="search_q" />
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" data-disable-with="Search" />
    </form></h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What makes the input invalid? Maybe catch all those exceptions, just like you have caught the blank and empty exception??

Comment: could you run your application then post here the full html code??(via browser's "View Page Source")

Comment: For the purpose of my current app, "invalid" input is any empty input or input containing all white space. I am not looking to perform any other checks at the moment, only to enable multiple submission attempts.

Comment: could you also include welcome.js?

Comment: i can't replicate your problem with the code you have provided(to do some debugging on it), also you have multiple HTML tags in your HTML mark-up which i believe is wrong. we also have multiple SO questions related to form submit try to read them and update your code... https://www.google.com.ph/#q=javascript+form+onsubmit

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do, I was a bit confused with your question. The simple answer would be to use jqBootstrapValidation, if I still don't get it, then clearly I am still confused: https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm(f) {
    var ele = document.forms[f].elements;
    var allValid = true;
    for (var i in ele) {
        if (!isChar(ele[i]) && ele[i].type!="radio" && ele[i].type!="checkbox") {
            allValid = false;
            ele[i].style.borderColor = "red";
        }
    }
    if (!allValid) {
        f.reset()
    }
}
```

This code will check each field of your form to make sure there is at least 1 character in each element, as long as it's not a checkbox or radio button. Feel free to mix and match that `if` statement however you see fit. In the loop, if any of the fields are not valid, it sets the `allValid` flag to false and upon exiting the loop and evaluating that flag for false, it resets your form. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The trick to multiple attempts was that I needed to find a way to remove the disable attribute after it was set on submit. I believe the disabled attribute appears after submitting as a result of the rails generated data-disable-with attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be that on submit, the input of type submit was given the disabled option and this what not reset after validating the data. My code is still a work in process, but here is my not yet DRY solution:

```
// welcome.js
function prepareEventHandler() {
    document.getElementById("new_search").onsubmit = validateForm
}

function validateForm() {
    var q = document.getElementById("search_q").value;
    var trimmed_q = q.trim();
    if (trimmed_q.length < 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    prepareEventHandler();
}

// (doesn't work in older IEs)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "true");

    document.getElementById("search_q").onkeyup = function() {
        var val = document.getElementById("search_q").value;
        var trimmed_q = val.trim();
        if(trimmed_q != '') {
            document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    };
}, false);
```